# How to run multi Observables conurrently in RxJava?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, rx-java

I am developing an Android App.

I want to show two values in the UI.
The values are retrieved from the API Server, and I am using the Retrofit to get them.

Here is my ApiService interface(Retrofit):

```
interface ApiService {
    @Get
    fun getData1(): Observable<String>

    @Get
    fun getData2(): Observable<String>
}
```

And below is my Presenter code:

```
val data1 = apiService.getData1().map { "d1" to it }
val data2 = apiService.getData1().map { "d2" to it }

Observable.just(data1, data2)
        .flatMap { it }
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe { (type, data) ->
            when (type) {
                "d1" -> view.showData1(data)
                "d2" -> view.showData2(data)
            }
        }
```

It works fine.
But this works sequentially.
After the first request "getData1()" is done, the second request "getData2()" is sent.

I want to send them concurrently.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve concurrent connection using [zip](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html) operator with [RxKotlin](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxKotlin).

Example)

```
val data1 = apiService.getData1()
val data2 = apiService.getData1()

Observables.zip(data1, data2)
   .subscribe { data ->
       view.showData1(data.first)
       view.showData2(data.second)
   }.addTo(compositeDisposable)
```

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, this will not run the `getData` operations concurrently.  You can illustrate this with a test with a mock `getData` that prints out the thread in use.  You could fix this by adding `subscribeOn`.  That is, change to `val data1 = apiService().getData1().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())`, for example.